# Are there any other examples where "weak" and "strong" are confused in mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

What are some examples of logically weak (when there are more objects satisfying) but being called 'strong' or logically strong (when there are fewer objects satisfying) being called 'weak'?

Comment: There are two partial orders on a Coxeter group $W$, often called the weak Bruhat order and the strong Bruhat order. Every relation in the weak order is a relation in the strong order, but not conversely. So, to say $u \leq v$ in weak order is a *stronger* statement than to say $u \leq v$ in strong order. However, note that nowadays it is more common to refer to "weak Bruhat order" as just "weak order" and "strong Bruhat order" as just "Bruhat order."

Comment: I always tell myself the strong Bruhat order is stronger in the architectural sense, as the extra edges in the Hasse diagram hold it together better.

Comment: @SamHopkins Interesting; I have never found this terminology confusing. It seems natural to me that a "partial" ordering is "weaker" than a "total" ordering. So the closer you are to a total ordering, the stronger it is, and the closer you are to an antichain, the weaker the ordering is.

Comment: Strong induction is stronger than weak induction because it has the same conclusion, but weaker hypothesis. So what makes you say that it is a “weaker condition” than weak induction? (What do you mean by “condition” here, anyway?)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek According to the page I linked to, using (weak) induction in Peano arithmetic is equivalent to strong induction + additional axiom (every element is either the first element or a successor). That seems to be telling me that strong induction allows for more models.

Comment: The top-voted answer to the linked question is quite confusing. First, what it calls strong induction is rather different from actual strong induction. Strong induction is the schema $\forall x\,(\forall y\,(y<x\to P(y))\to P(x))\to\forall x\,P(x)$, whereas (weak) induction is the schema $P(0)\land\forall x\,(P(x)\to P(S(x)))\to\forall x\,P(x)$, where $P$ are formulas in the language of arithmetic $(0,S,+,\cdot,<)$, possibly using other free variables. These are formulated in the context of first-order arithmetic, and it makes hardly any sense to consider them without a suitable background ...

Comment: ... theory such as Robinson’s arithmetic Q (or better, $\mathrm{PA}^-$). Over such a background theory: (1) strong induction for any particular formula $P$ implies weak induction for the same formula, but (2) in general, weak induction for $P$ does not imply strong induction for $P$. Thus strong induction is *strictly stronger* than weak induction in this sense. However, strong induction for $P$ follows from weak induction for a sutable different formula, hence if you postulate both schemata for all formulas, they are *equivalent*. Now, what happens if you drop the background theory? ...

Comment: ... Now, *neither* achema implies the other: this should be obvious from the fact that one states a property of $0$ and $S$, whereas the other a property of $<$ (one can easily produce models to show this formally). Thus, it is not possible to prove any implication between them without assuming connecting axioms that relate $<$ to $0$ and $S$. The most obvious way of shoiwing that strong induction implies weak induction needs not just $\forall x\,(x=0\lor\exists y\,S(y)=x)$, but also $\forall x\,x<S(x)$. On the other hand, the obvious way of showing that weak induction implies ...

Comment: ... strong induction needs $\forall x\, \neg(x<0)$ and $\forall x,y\,(y<S(x)\to y<x\lor y=x)$. However, these axioms themselves do not follow from the two induction schemata, hence it is not true that their combination is equivalent to one of these schemata plus a simple axiom like $\forall x\,(x=0\lor\exists y\,S(y)=x)$. To see this, note that the two induction schemata together are valid in a model $(\mathbb N,0,S,+,\cdot,\prec)$ where $\prec$ is any ordering of type $\omega$ on $\mathbb N$ (even if unrelated to the stardard ordering). Thus, no reasonable “connecting axioms” ...

Comment: ... relating $0$ and $S$ to $<$ are actual consequences of the two inductions.

Comment: Also, note that all answers to the linked question *do* rely on various axioms from the background theory, so frankly I have no idea where you came up with the reading that  “weak induction is equivalent to strong induction + additional axiom”. This is your misinterpretation.

Comment: Let me add that since the two schemata are independent without further axioms, this also means that you can *pick and choose* the base theory so that one schema implies the other, but not vice versa. But this does not say anything abount the relative strength of the two schemata, it just means that the base theory is inadequate. For example, take for the base theory the usual axioms of Robinson’s arithmetic concerning $0,S,+,\cdot$ plus $\neg(x<0)$ and $x<S(y)\leftrightarrow x<y\lor x=y$. Over this base theory the strong and weak induction schemata are equivalent, as they should. ...

Comment: ... Now, if you drop the axiom $x=0\lor\exists y\,S(y)=x$, then strong induction does not imply weak induction, and weak induction is equivalent to strong induction plus the omitted axiom $x=0\lor\exists y\,S(y)=x$. But in the opposite way, if you drop the $\neg(x<0)$ axiom instead, then weak induction does not imply strong induction, and strong induction is equivalent to weak induction plus the omitted axiom $\neg(x<0)$.

Comment: Thanks. I thought strong induction and (weak) induction had [confusing names](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37944/induction-vs-strong-induction) but this is not a good example of what I was curious about. I revised the question.

Answer (score 27):

Munkres's book *Topology* (p. 78) contains the following warning about coarser and finer topologies:

> Many mathematicians use the words "weaker" and "stronger" in this context. Unfortunately, some of them (particularly analysts) are apt to say that $\mathcal T'$ is stronger than $\mathcal T$ if $\mathcal T' \supset \mathcal T$, while others (particularly topologists) are apt to say that $\mathcal T'$ is weaker than $\mathcal T$ in the same situation! If you run across the terms "strong topology" or "weak topology" in some book, you will have to decide from the context which inclusion is meant. We shall not use these terms in this book.

For instance, the 'weak topology' in the definition of a CW complex is the *finest* topology for which all cell inclusions are continuous. But weak topologies on a topological vector space $V$ are usually the *coarsest* topology for which certain maps $V \to \mathbf R$ are continuous.

The difference here comes from whether you think a topology is weaker if it has more opens or if more sequences converge.

(Like Munkres, I have adapted the convention to stick to the unambiguous terms *coarser* and *finer*.)

Comment: 'Weak topology' occurs when the situation is *at the lower edge of continuity* (with the minimal number of continuous maps): For a topological space $X$, the finer the topology on $X$ is, the less possibility of continuity a map $f$ with **target** $X$ will have; Conversely, the coarser the topology on $X$ is, the less possibility of continuity a map $f$ with **source** $X$ will have. Similarly, 'strong topology' occurs when the situation is *at the upper edge of continuity*. In this sense, the use of 'strong' and 'weak' is subtle, but not quite 'confused'.

Comment: but I wonder how many people would really call "stronger" a coarser topology. My guess is very few. I think the situation is not symmetric.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that [strong monoidal functors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+functor) were originally called "weak monoidal functors". The newer name indicates that it's a stronger condition than being a lax monoidal functor, while the original name indicates that it's a weaker condition than being a strict monoidal functor.

Answer (score 8):

There are certainly examples where the terms "strong" and "weak" can be confusing, though I'm not sure I would call any of them "mistakes" per se.  Even in your example of "strong induction" versus "weak induction," I am not sure what you mean when you say that "strong induction is a weaker condition." Are you saying that if an induction is weak then it is also strong, but not necessarily vice versa?  That doesn't seem to be true, at least not according to how I've heard the terms "strong induction" and "weak induction" used.

But the example that comes to mind is the "weak law of large numbers" and the "strong law of large numbers."  The strong law is so called because its *conclusion* (almost sure convergence) is stronger than the conclusion of the weak law (convergence in probability). However, the terminology can give the impression that the weak law is a straightforward corollary of the strong law, since that's what we normally mean by saying that Theorem A is "stronger" than Theorem B.  But the weak law does not follow straightforwardly from the strong law, because the hypotheses of the weak law are different.

The type of example alluded to by [Sam Hopkins in a comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442891/are-there-any-other-examples-where-weak-and-strong-are-confused-in-mathemati#comment1143076_442891) also arises frequently.  A structure on a set may be called "weaker" than another if there is less structure.  So for example, a topology $\mathscr{U}$ on a set $X$ is *weaker* than a topology $\mathscr{V}$ on $X$ if $\mathscr{U} \subseteq \mathscr{V}$. But this means that for a given subset $U \subseteq X$, the condition $U\in \mathscr{U}$ is *stronger* than the condition $U\in \mathscr{V}$.  I wouldn't call this an "error" but some people might find it confusing.

Comment: In the topology example, I thought the usual terms were "finer" and "coarser"? EDIT: Nevermind, you are right, "stronger" and "weaker" are also used for this...

Comment: @SamHopkins That terminology is used, but certainly "weak" is used as well. Certainly the terminology "weak-* topology" is pretty entrenched; I've never heard the Banach-Alaoglu theorem ever stated without using the term "weak-* topology."

Comment: In what sense are the hypotheses of the weak law of large numbers different to those of the strong law of large numbers? Obviously, one *can* come up with situations where the conclusion of the weak law holds and that of the strong law doesn't. But aren't the names both generally understood to refer to the case of a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with finite mean?

Comment: @JamesMartin Wikipedia lists a few examples where [the weak law holds but the strong law doesn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Differences_between_the_weak_law_and_the_strong_law). In particular, finite mean isn't always necessary for the weak law to hold.

Comment: @TimothyChow Yes, I did already write that there are situations where the conclusion of the weak law holds and the conclusion of the strong law doesn't!! So, in your answer you are talking about a theorem called "the weak law of large numbers" -- what theorem do you yourself mean by that name?

Comment: @JamesMartin If you read carefully, you'll see that I did not say that there is a single specific theorem called "the weak law of large numbers." In my experience, the term refers to a family of theorems. The situation is similar with the "law of the iterated logarithm," for which there's the vanilla case of i.i.d. variables with mean zero and bounded increment, but for which there are also other variants that go by the same name. The word "law" tends to be interpreted as a certain kind of behavior, rather than as a specific theorem.

Comment: Maybe it would have been clearer if I had said that the weak law does not *always* follow straightforwardly from the strong law, because the hypotheses *can be* different? In any case, the point is that it can be confusing: if the weak law is just an easy corollary of the strong law, then why do people bother talking about the weak law?

Comment: Yes, and indeed if one wants to write clear mathematics, I think it's a super-good habit to distinguish carefully between a theorem, and the conclusion of a theorem -- otherwise things often get confusing. As you say, if "law" is interpreted as meaning a certain type of behavior rather than a theorem, then it genuinely *is* the case that the strong law (behavior) implies the weak law (behavior) for any given sequence.

Answer (score 4):

As an example where the adjectives "weak" and "strong" refer to hypotheses, rather than conclusions, a favorite of mine is (Gelfand-Pettis) "weak" vector-valued integrals, as juxtaposed to (Bochner) "strong" vector-valued integrals.

Apart from other hypotheses, such as that the vector space is locally convex and quasi-complete, the "weak" integral $\int_X f(x)\,d\mu(x)$ if a $V$-valued function $f$ is characterized by
$$
\lambda\Big(\int_X f(x)\,d\mu(x)\Big) \;=\; \int_X \lambda(f(x))\,d\mu(x)
$$
for all $\lambda$ in the continuous dual of $V$, noting that the right-hand side is just a scalar-valued integral. By Hahn-Banach, there is at most one such. Then, under various (useful-in-practice) hypotheses, one proves existence. To me, it's fairly amazing that the "weak" (because it refers to the dual) condition gives so much.

In contrast, the "strong" (Bochner) integral *constructs* an "integral", in analogy with Riemann and Lebesgue integrals, and then *proves* it has the desired properties (which would/do also follow from the "weak" condition!)

Comment: But in this case isn't at least the logical strengths correct? In that a Bochner integrable function is Gelfand-Pettis integrable?

Comment: @WillieWong, ah, well, yes, the _hypotheses's_ implications run in that direction, for sure. (Though some traditional formulations of Bochner integrals are too restrictive... I think Anton Deitmar showed that quasi-complete, locally convex, which is needed for "weak", also works for "strong"...)

Answer (score 3):

It is sometimes said that the axioms of a group can be "weakened" by merely requiring the existence of a left identity element, and left inverses. A priori it seems that replacing the two-sided axioms with their one-sided counterparts could lead to more models. However, it turns out that in a semigroup with both a left identity and left inverses, the left identity must also be a right identity, and the left inverses are also right inverses. Therefore, the "weakened" axioms have exactly the same models as the usual group axioms, meaning that the term "weakened" is perhaps misleading. On the other hand, in a general algebraic structure, the existence of a left identity is still a strictly weaker condition than a two-sided identity. Thus, a collection of individually weaker axioms might still yield the same models as a collection of their individually stronger counterparts. This is an elementary observation, but an important one, since it reinforces how the terms "stronger" and "weaker" are sensitive to context.

Comment: Perhaps more striking is that commutativity of addition is superfluous for commutative rings, but obviously very strong in general.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: Did you mean to say that it is superfluous for unital rings?

Comment: Well, all my rings have an identity element (otherwise they are rngs).

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: Assuming that all rings are unital, I think that commutativity of addition is a superfluous axiom even for *noncommutative* rings. It follows by expanding the product $(1+1)(x+y)$ (see [Bill Dubuque's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609364/why-is-ring-addition-commutative?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Comment: Yes, that was what I wanted to refer to — but I added an extra commutative in my comment.