# Interesting examples of vacuous / void entities

Tags: lo.logic, big-list

I included this footnote in a paper in which I mentioned that the number of partitions of the empty set is 1 (every member of any partition is a non-empty set, and of course every member of the empty set is a non-empty set):

> "Perhaps as a result of studying set theory, I was surprised when I learned that some respectable combinatorialists consider such things as this to be mere convention.  One of them even said a case could be made for setting the number of partitions to 0 when $n=0$.  By stark contrast, Gian-Carlo Rota wrote in \cite{Rota2}, p.~15, that 'the kind of mathematical reasoning that physicists find unbearably pedantic' leads not only to the conclusion that the elementary symmetric function in no variables is 1, but straight from there to the theory of the Euler characteristic, so that 'such reasoning does pay off.'  The only other really sexy example I know is from applied statistics: the non-central chi-square distribution with zero degrees of freedom, unlike its 'central' counterpart, is non-trivial."

The cited paper was: G-C.~Rota, [Geometric Probability](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03025223), *Mathematical Intelligencer*, 20 (4), 1998, pp. 11--16.  The paper in which my footnote appears is the first one you see [here](http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_13/v13i1toc.html), doi: [10.37236/1027](https://doi.org/10.37236/1027).

**Question:** What other really gaudy examples are there?

Some remarks:

- From one point of view, the whole concept of vacuous truth is silly.  It is a counterintuitive but true proposition that Minneapolis is at a higher latitude than Toronto.  "Ex falso quodlibet" (or whatever the Latin phrase is) and so if you believe Toronto is a more northerly locale than Minneapolis, it will lead you into all sorts of mistakes like $2 + 2 = 5,$ etc.  But that is nonsense.
- From another point of view, in its proper mathematical context, it makes perfect sense.
- People use examples like propositions about all volcanoes made of pure gold, etc.  That's bad pedagogy and bad in other ways.  What if I ask whether all cell phones in the classroom have been shut off?  If there are no cell phones in the room (that *is* more realistic than volcanoes made of gold, isn't it??) then the correct answer is "yes".  That's a good example, showing, if only in a small way, the utility of the concept when used properly.
- I don't think it's mere convention that the number of partitions of the empty set is 1; it follows logically from some basic things in logic.  Those don't make sense in some contexts (see "Minneapolis", "Toronto", etc., above) but in fact the *only* truth value that can be assigned to $\text{“}F\Longrightarrow F\text{''}$ or $\text{“}F\Longrightarrow T\text{''}$ that makes it possible to fill in the truth table without knowing the content of the false proposition (and satisfies the other desiderata?) is $T.$  That's a fact whose truth doesn't depend on conventions.

Comment: I agree that any standard definition of "partition" will give the empty set one partition. I suspect that the reason some people think of this conclusion as a mere convention is that they are reminded of some superficially similar situations. Is $1$ a prime number? Is $R$ a prime ideal in $R$? Is the empty space connected? Is a trivial module irreducible? Life is easier if you say "no" to all of these, even though this at first seems to call for a special convention. 

Comment: It makes sense to say 1 is not prime because when you're factoring a number and you got $60 = 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 5$, you don't want to go on to $60 = 1 \times 1\times 2 \times1 \times 1\times 2 \times 3 \times 1\times \times 1\times\times 1\times 1\times 5\times 1\times1$, etc.

Comment: (BTW, "sexy vacuity" was not allowed as a title of this thread because it's only 12 characters.  Hence the trailing dots.)

Comment: have a look at the excellent example: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22189/what-is-your-favorite-strange-function/22236#22236

Comment: It might make sense to say $1$ is not prime because $R/\langle 1\rangle$ hasn't got a non-trivial unit.  On the other hand, the quotient hasn't any zero-divisors...  On the other other hand, if we're only looking at the rig $\mathbb{N}$, then $1$ has the wrong number of binary factorizations: only $1=1\times 1$, but $2=2\times 1 = 1\times 2$. Counting binary factorizations is a useful thing to do because, e.g., exactly the nonzero squares have an odd number of them.

Comment: @some guy: “the quotient hasn’t any zero-divisors”: true, but nonetheless, it *isn't* an integral domain!  …at least if you define that as a ring where “any product of non-zero elements is non-zero”, since in the trivial ring, the empty product of non-zero elements is zero :-)  (I guess most people enjoying this question will agree that this is the “right” definition of integral domain, not the more common version which just considers binary products, but I think plenty of mathematicians might disagree.)

Comment: Incidentally, while all the answers so far are certainly nice, none yet seem sexy in the same sort of way that the $\chi$-square distribution cited is.  The answers so far are mostly in some sense trivialities — beautiful, widely misunderstood, important trivialities, but trivialities nonetheless.  It would be nice to see more along the lines of the original example given!

Comment: @Michael Hardy: am I the only person who doesn't actually understand what the question being asked is?

Comment: @Quiaochu Yuan: “vacuity” here means, I think, taking some concept with parameters (e.g. “the determinant of the zero endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^k$”) and setting some parameter equal to $0$, or the empty set, or something similarly trivial.  “Sexy” is when the result is enlightening and/or surprising: the determinant of that endomorphism is 1!

Comment: The proper way to define a prime ideal is as follows: A prime ideal is a proper ideal $p$ such that $ab\in \mathfrak{p} \text{ and } b\notin \mathfrak{p}\Rightarrow a\in \mathfrak{p}$.  This excludes the $0$ ring from having any primes, and further, it allows us to define an integral domain to be precisely a ring where the $0$ ideal is prime.

Comment: @Harry: Agreed; it can also be nicely restated as “an ideal is prime if its complement is closed under finite products”, which shows why properness and the other condition really belong together.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Maybe you are the only one.  But I can't be sure of that.  The question asks for other examples of non-trivial and interesting mathematics arising out of seemingly trivial instances of vacuity.

Comment: Oh, let's start flaming about $ 0^0 $ and the degree of the constant zero polynomial while we're here.  

Comment: "...it will lead you into all sorts of mistakes like 2 + 2 = 5, etc..." But I know all sorts of silly people who believe things like "the Axiom of Choice is false", yet they've managed to convince themselves they won't run into any mistakes in ZF¬C.

Comment: I like examples where a trivial/vacuous case helps determine the "right" definition in the general case, e.g., the norm of a morphism of normed spaces below. I like examples which begin an induction in a surprisingly vacuous case, yet the induction still works. And I like examples where the same principle gives a useful answer in multiple cases - e.g. in an order lattice, the sup/join of the empty set is the least element, and the inf/meet is the greatest: for the extended real numbers, $\inf\emptyset=\infty$ and for subsets of a set X, the empty intersection is X.  

Comment: de Boor's "An empty exercise" on vacuity in linear algebra: http://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/Approx/empty.pdf or here:
http://dx.doi.org/10.1145%2F122272.122273

Comment: At the same time you can ask whether all cell phones in the room are turned on. And the correct answer must be "yes", again.

Comment: Reminds me in a discussion at a students party, on how many possible combinations of coins there would be to toss into the cigarette slot-machine to get a pack of cigarettes. After some "brilliant" guy came up with the claim that one single coin would not be a "combination" I stated that even tossing no coins would be a combination (though not one for which you get cigarettes (not even an empty pack)). It contributed to the good atmosphere (and shows about the tendency of human perception to generate exceptions (maybe (and mathematicians hate exceptions (maybe)))).

Comment: @MichaelHardy why did you add fake math mode in the title?

Comment: @YCor : I don't recall with certainty, but I suspect the reason is one of the dumb robots decided my subject line was not acceptable. Sometimes they do that; it's happened to me more than once.

Comment: @YCor : ok, I've just checked. I get an error message saying subject lines must be at least 15 characters. That one is simple, but sometimes the software decides a title is unacceptable for reasons that are mysterious.

Comment: And sometimes a user decides a title is unacceptable for reasons that are maybe not as mysterious.

Comment: Maybe this can be relevant, and at least I find it funny: https://mathoverflow.net/a/376666/167834

Comment: @LSpice I meant the link to my answer to a different question. The link I gave seems to work.

Comment: Yes, you are [right](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/interesting-examples-of-vacuous-void-entities/409106#comment1100446_45951); I got confused.  I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 155):

How many open covers does the empty topological space have?  Not one, not none, but two: the empty cover $\varnothing$, since its union is $\bigcup\varnothing=\varnothing$, and the cover $\{\varnothing\}$, since its union is also $\bigcup\{\varnothing\} =\varnothing$.

This comes up when using the Grothendieck plus-construction to sheafify a presheaf.  Apply the construction to the (nonseparated) presheaf $P:\mathcal{O}(X)^\mathrm{op}\to \mathrm{Set}$ sending every open set to the set $A$, with $|A|\geq 2$.  Then the presheaf $P^+:\mathcal{O}(X)^\mathrm{op}\to\mathrm{Set}$ agrees with $P$ on every open set except $\varnothing\subseteq X$, where $P^+(\varnothing)$ is now a one-element set $\{*\}.$  This is because the matching families for the cover $\{\varnothing\}$ of $\varnothing$ (of which there is one for each $a\in A$) are all set equal to the unique matching family for the refining cover $\varnothing\subseteq\{\varnothing\}$ of $\varnothing$.

This elementary example comes from III.5 of "Sheaves in Geometry and Logic", by Moerdijk and MacLane.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a map from {\empty} to \empty, as you would expect for a cover.

Comment: I'm using cover in the sense of "A set of subsets of X, whose union is all of X". Doesn't the map usually go from the disjoint union of the elements of the cover to the covered space? In this case that's a map from $\varnothing$ to $\varnothing$...

Comment: The statement you wrote in English is correct, but your notation is deceptive.  The union of zero sets is empty, and the singleton union of the empty set is also empty, but you shouldn't write a union of singleton sets.

Comment: Here I'm using the notation that if $S$ is a set (in particular, of sets) then $\bigcup S=\bigcup_{A\in S}A$.

Comment: I laughed out loud at this one! At least continuous functions patch easily over both open covers :)

Comment: That is bizarre.

Comment: Well, yeah! Union being an operation $P(P(S)) \to P(S)$, i.e. a function from a 2-element set to a 1-element set if $S$ is empty.

Comment: @OwenBiesel : You shouldn't write {$\varnothing$} with the {curly braces} excluded from the MathJax code. I've changed it to $\{\varnothing\}. \qquad$

Comment: Thanks, Michael, I don't know why I would have done that. I've changed the rest.

Comment: Maybe an open cover of a topological space should be defined as a collection of **nonempty** open sets that covers the space? Is there any good reason for including the empty set in a cover?

Comment: @bof, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/interesting-examples-of-vacuous-void-entities#comment922044_46073), I think the spirit of this question is:  is there any good reason for *not* including it (or, rather, not allowing it to be included)?  The first silly example I can think of for why one might allow it: if we do so, then we can say things like "if $\mathcal A$ is a cover of $A$ and $\mathcal B$ is a cover of $B$, then $\{U \cap V \mathrel: \text{$U \in \mathcal A$ and $V \in \mathcal B$}\}$ is a cover of $A \cap B$."

Comment: @LSpice Good point. Likewise, if we allow $\varnothing$ as an element of a partition, then we can say "if $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal Q$ are partitions of $E$, then so is $\{P\cap Q:P\in\mathcal P,\ Q\in\mathcal Q\}$" instead of having to write $\{P\cap Q:P\in\mathcal P,\ Q\in\mathcal Q,\ P\cap Q\ne\varnothing\}$. Then each equivalence relation would correspond to not one but two partitions. But we can fix that by *requiring* $\varnothing$ to be an element of every partition.

Comment: @bof, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/interesting-examples-of-vacuous-void-entities/46073#comment1005952_46073), it depends on what your meaning of 'correspond' is.  To me, an equivalence relation corresponds to its set of equivalence classes, and the empty set is not an equivalence class.  Of course, one could instead make an equivalence relation correspond to the set containing its equivalence classes *and the empty set*, but this definition seems more complicated to me.

Comment: @bof, oh, I think I see now; I think you are [referring](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/interesting-examples-of-vacuous-void-entities/46073#comment1005952_46073) to the fact that, with the correspondence I [propose](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/interesting-examples-of-vacuous-void-entities/46073#comment1005953_46073), partitions one piece of which is empty no longer correspond to equivalence relations.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 60):

There is a big difference between statements such as, one the one hand "the empty sum is zero" or "0!=1" and on the other hand "1 is not a prime number". In my opinion, the latter does involve a convention (i.e., a choice) but the former does not.

The first definition of a prime that comes to mind (and came historically, I guess) is "a natural number with no divisors except 1 and itself". This is a perfectly reasonable notion, but it leads to unpleasant contortions when one tries to state the prime decomposition theorem, including uniqueness. A similar phenomenon explains why an irreducible space is nonempty by definition. In these cases, the definition has been tailored to the need of getting cleaner statements. The question "is the empty space connected?" falls into the same category; I find it strange that the more common convention (which is yes) does not match the other two.

In the case of the empty sum, 0 is the only conceivable value, the other choice being "undefined": a mathematician hostile to the empty set might define finite (nonempty) sums by induction, starting from the one-term case and leaving the empty case meaningless. This would not lead to contradictions, only to lots of traps in proofs because whenever you take the sum of some finite set of numbers you first have to check that it is not empty, or treat the empty case separately.

And of course, if you run the inductive definition "backwards" from 1 term to 0 term you immediately find the right value for the empty sum. This is an efficient way to convince students.

Comment: Laurent, this is a very interesting and  convincingly illustrated point of view.

Comment: I once heard it asserted that Euclid and his coevals did not consider 1 a prime number because they did not consider 1 a number.  That seems consistent with our own colloquial usage when we say "A number of people commented on this idea."

Comment: Well said, Laurent. 

Comment: @Micheal, in classical greek neither one nor two are properly numbers.

Comment: @Laurent: From my years in Rennes, I remember a coffee-break conversation (back when the room was still on the 4th floor) where people were discussing whether it made sense to talk about the action of the null group on the empty set. (I don't think you were involved in that discussion, but I'm pretty sure Antoine Ducros was.) It stuck in my mind, I could never quite decide if it was very silly or too deep for me.

Comment: @Mariano. So the greeks instinctively knew that 2 is a very odd prime.

Comment: On the other hand, the closely related notion of prime ideal can be very naturally formulated in such a way that the analog of "1 is not prime" comes out as a consequence. E. g. you define a prime ideal of a bounded lattice $L$ to be a subset whose characteristic function $L\to\{\text{false},\text{true}\}$ is a $\textit{bounded}$ lattice homomorphism. Now bounded means in particular that the top of $L$ should not belong to the ideal and the bottom should belong to it, so both "improper" primes $L$ and $\varnothing$ are naturally excluded. Then the only "unnatural" assumption is true$\ne$false

Comment: A prime number is one such that whenever it divides a product, it divides at least one of the factors. 1 divides a product of no factors, therefore it cannot be prime. (Interestingly, this definition makes 0 a prime number; [this may actually be defensible](/a/46077/157594).) By the same token: a connected space is one such that whenever it is presented as a disjoint union, it is contained in one of the summands. The empty space is a disjoint union of no summands, therefore it is not connected.

Answer (score 56):

Over the reals, $\sup \emptyset = -\infty$ and $\inf \emptyset = \infty$.

Comment: This is another one which comes from universal properties.  One can regard a poset as a category where a \le b iff there is an arrow from a to b.  Then the supremum is the colimit and the infimum is the limit.  The empty supremum is the empty colimit, which is the initial object (if it exists), and the empty infimum is the empty limit, which is the final object (if it exists).  And I guess you mean "extended reals."

Comment: If one defines the distance between two points in a (suitable) space as the length of the shortest path, then this one implies the distance is infinite if there's no path.  So that's one way this one is useful.

Comment: This is an example I would have given. In particular, in the extended reals, inf A is only less than or equal sup A if A is nonempty. The same logic explains why the zero polynomial has degree $-\infty$ and why the empty set has dimension $-\infty$.

Comment: @Michael Hardy : Thank you I love that one for its semantic consistency.So far I had always look at it only as a saving device to be consistent with equations ( handling exceptions in a transparent way). But now I can   think of it as : It takes an infinite time to find no path just as it takes the same infinite time to run on an infinite path.

Comment: @David MJC: I disagree with your dimension convention.  There are many situations where the empty set should not have a uniquely defined dimension.  For example, one may consider a closed $n$-manifold as a cobordism between empty $n-1$-manifolds.

Comment: Scott, I think you are talking about the empty (n-1)-manifold there, not the empty set :)

Comment: The fact that $\sup\varnothing\leqslant\sup(\text{anything})$ and $\inf\varnothing\geqslant\inf(\text{anything})$ is quite convenient in e. g. programming.

Comment: Do we also have the convention $\max\emptyset=-\infty$ and $\min\emptyset=\infty$?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger, I think that [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/sexy-vacuity#comment594222_46150) would be a bad convention, since the maximum and minimum of a set, if they exist, should belong to it (whereas there is no such expectation for the supremum and infimum).

Comment: In an ordered set, of course, sup and inf  may not exist. In particular, $\sup(\emptyset)$ is the smallest element, if (and only if) this exists. This stresses the necessity of specifying what ordered set we work in, as @QiaochuYuan wrote. Since $\sup(\emptyset)$ does not exist in the reals, we implicitly use the extended reals to take the sup and inf in. The reason this convention is harmless is that every set of reals has an extended sup (resp. inf), which is the same as the real one when applicable.

Answer (score 49):

An elementary example, but pedagogically nice: a standard early induction proof example is that you can tile any $2^n \times 2^n$ square with one unit square removed, using L-shaped tiles of three unit squares each.

Surprisingly (to me), many textbooks take the base case as $n=2$.  The better ones use $n=1$.  But the version in The Book, though, surely starts at $n = 0$!

(Of course, I understand the pedagogy of not starting at 0: it’s usually best to make one point at a time.  Trying to use this single example to teach about both induction and vacuity simultaneously would end up confusing most students.  But when it’s not needed for the former, it does work nicely for the latter, I think!)

Comment: When inductively calculating homology of spheres I like to take the ${-1}$-sphere (empty space) as base case.

Comment: Better take the unreduced suspension then! You do that to students?

Comment: You wrote "The better ones use $n=1$. But the version in The Book surely starts at $n=0!$. But isn't $0!=1$? And yes, that totally on-topic pun is intended!

Comment: Besides the $(-1)$-sphere, continued fractions are better defined from $n=-1$: $p_n/q_n=[a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n]$ so that $p_0=a_0$, $q_0=1$, but also $p_{-1}=1$, $q_{-1}=0$.

Comment: Sort of related: if I remember correctly, you can tile any $n \times n$ square using the above-mentioned L-shaped tiles, plus up to one $1 \times 1$ tile, for any nonnegative integer $n$ apart from 3.

Comment: The usual inductive argument I know for this uses the placement of an explicit L tile to extend from the case of the $2^n\times 2^n$ square to the $2^{n+1}\times2^{n+1}$ case. How do you make this work in the scenario where you're starting your induction at $0$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: note that $n=0$ means a $1 \times 1$ square, not $0 \times 0$.  So the first induction step goes from the $1 \times 1$ to $2 \times 2$, and does indeed work uniformly with all the rest: put an L down in the “center”; now each of the $1 \times 1$ subsquares has one square removed, so the case $n = 0$ tells us how to tile those.

Comment: Ahhh! Okay, that makes a lot more sense, yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 40):

Counting is a special case I think: the number of ways of doing nothing is always 1, because you do exactly that, nothing. The number of ways of doing something impossible is 0, because you can't do it. That's why we have:
$$ \binom{n}{0}=1 \quad \text{but} \quad \binom{n}{n+1}=0.$$
So I don't think your partition example or the cell phone example are really about vacuous truth the same way the Minneapolis example is. Though if pressed I'm not sure how I would formulate precisely how to make the distinction.

Comment: A zillion times I've had undergraduates ask me why 0! is 1, and that's not hard to answer by saying if you divide 4! by 4 you get 3!, and if you divide that by 3 you get 2!, and keep going and see where the pattern leads.  But When they ask why $\binom{6}{0} = 1$, there's a bad way to answer that and a good way.  The bad way talks about the empty set, etc.  Here's the good way.  Toss a coin 6 times; in how many ways can you get "heads" 3 times?  The list of 20 includes HHHttt, HHtHtt, HHttHt, etc.  Then do the same for 2 out of 6.  Then 1 out of 6.  Then 0 out of 6.  Simple.

Comment: @MichaelHardy why is the toin explanations better than the empty set explanation? As for me, they are equivalent.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "toin"? But how do you get students to understand why such a thing as the empty set should ever be contemplated? Students "know" that in mathematics one accepts absurdities as infallible dogmas (and it's the fault of mathematicians that they think that) and so they accept the empty set because they're told to. But what if you have a student who actually wants to understand why such a thing as an empty set is worth considering?

Comment: @MichaelHardy, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1049781), in [the relevant comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1049658) @‍FedorPetrov doubtless typo'd ‘coin’ as ‘toin’.

Comment: @FedorPetrov : It appears to me that you have no idea what question the example was intended to answer. Obviously, AFTER one has established that there is such a thing as an empty set and AFTER one has established certain basic things about vacuous truth, the two are equivalent. But the fact that it is AFTER those things means that it does nothing to address the question; it just ignores the question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Well, I was thinking about the undergraduates who establish the empty set before binomial coefficients. Otherwise, how was ${6\choose 0}$ defined for them?

Comment: @FedorPetrov : It is taught DOGMATICALLY to undergraduates that there is an empty set. Justification for having such an entity is rarely if ever provided.

Comment: @FedorPetrov : In favor of having such a concept as the empty set, I would say two things (1) contrary to what some non-mathematicians, and even a small number of mathematicians, seem to assume, including the concept of an empty set is not a bold philosophical position, and (2) it is what makes it possible to see that some problems are as simple as they really are. Excluding the empty set from the theory only complicates matters. I have in mind mainly propositions in combinatorics and probability, but probably others good examples exist.

Comment: @FedorPetrov : To speak of what happens AFTER one establishes that there is an empty set is to miss the point.

Answer (score 35):

1. The value of any sheaf on the empty set is the terminal object.
   (Consider the gluing condition for the empty open cover of the empty set.)
2. If $A→B$ is a morphism of sets, then we can define the factor set $B/A$.
   We have $B/∅=B⊔*$, where $*$ is a one-element set.
   (Consider the left adjoint of the forgetful functor from the category of pointed sets
   to the category of morphisms of sets.  Alternatively, observe that $B/A≅(B∖A)⊔*$.)
3. Sometimes the norm of a morphism of normed spaces $f: X→Y$
   is defined as $$\sup_{x∈X: x≠0} ‖f(x)‖/‖x‖$$ or as $$\sup_{x∈X: ‖x‖=1} ‖f(x)‖.$$
   This does not work for $X=0$.
   The correct definition is $$‖f‖=\sup_{x∈X: ‖x‖≤1} ‖f(x)‖.$$
   It also works for seminorms.
4. The zero ring is the terminal object in the category of unital rings.
   It is not an integral domain, nor a local ring or a field.
5. The empty manifold is not connected.
   Its number of connected components is 0.
   (Think of the following theorem: Every manifold is the coproduct of a unique
   family of connected manifolds.  The cardinality of the family equals the number of connected components.)
6. Examples in elementary mathematics abound.
   The zero vector space has an empty basis and a unique endomorphism $A$.
   The matrix of $A$ in the unique basis is empty and the determinant of $A$ is 1.
   There is exactly one function from the empty set to any other set (the empty function).
   Zero is a natural number, $0^0=1$, the sum of the empty family of numbers is 0,
   the product of the empty family of numbers is 1,
   the product or the coproduct of an empty family of objects in a category
   is the terminal or the initial object of this category,
   the monoidal product of the empty family of objects in a monoidal category is the monoidal unit.

Comment: I’ve long adored the fact that the determinant of the unique 0×0 matrix is one — *even though it’s a zero matrix*!

Comment: I'd say $0^0 =1$, not $0$ since it's an empty product.  And the series expansion $e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ doesn't work when $z=0$ unless $0^0=1$ (consider the first term). (But that's not the whole story, since $0^0$ is an indeterminate form since $g(x)^{f(x)}$ can approach any nonnegative number as $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ approach 0, depending on what $f$ and $g$ are.  However, if both are analytic, then the limit is 1.  And in order to make $g(x)^{f(x)}$ approach anything but 1, the point $(g(x),f(x)$ must approach 0 along a curve with the $g$ or $f$ axis as a tangent line.)

Comment: @Michael: Oops, I meant 0^0=1, of course.  This is a typo.

Comment: As I have commented elsewhere, 0^0 = 1 because there is one function from the empty set to the empty set.

Comment: I once ran into the issue mentioned in (3) when writing some foundational material about maps between modules for $p$-adic Banach algebras, but I came up with a different fix: because all these sets of norms were clearly living in the non-negative reals, I decreed that all sups should be taken in the set of non-negative reals. This fixed all problems at a stroke because the sup of the empty set was suddenly zero which is the answer one wants.

Comment: Re $0^0$: one has to be careful here. It's only people doing discrete sorts of maths who can assert with confidence that $0^0$ always seems to be 1. I am guessing that people doing analysis or something more continuous might sometimes want something else.

Comment: FWIW here's another comment about (3): in the world of $p$-adic Banach spaces you run into the issue that, even if $V$ is non-zero, the norm map from $V$ to the non-negative reals may not be surjective (it may even miss the number 1). So when I was writing about this stuff I defined $|f|$ to be the sup (within the set of non-negative reals) of $|f(x)|/|x|$ as $x$ ran through the non-zero elements of the space. This worked for me, but running over $x$ with $|x|=1$ did not. I think the fix in (3) above is unnatural because it singles out the number 1 as somehow important, and it isn't, here.

Comment: @Kevin: Do you have any concrete examples where it is beneficial to define 0^0 to be different from 1?

Comment: I am not an analyst but I would imagine if an analyst for some reason ended up analysing the function $y=0^x$ for $x$ in $[0,1]$ (perhaps as some degenerate case of some more general function) then they might want to set $0^0=0$ as a useful convention, for them, at that point. All I am saying is that it is not inconceivable, to me, that perhaps sometimes $0^0$ isn't $1$. On the other hand it really is inconceivable, to me, that e.g. the determinant of the unique $0\times 0$ matrix should ever be anything other than 1.

Comment: If one wants exponentiation to be continuous (as an analyst might) then `$0^0$` has to be indeterminate.  But I've never been motivated to make `$0^x$` continuous at 0, because it becomes undefined just to the left of 0 (i.e., $x<0$) anyway.  So I prefer to say `$0^0=1$` and tolerate a little discontinuity.

Comment: @Kevin: Do you have any specific use for this convention in mind?  For example, the standard notation for polynomials and power series is wrong unless 0^0=1.  Also the binomial theorem is wrong unless 0^0=1.  Is there any interesting theorem that is wrong unless 0^0=0?

Comment: Property (1) is not a "mere curiosity that's never used", as some beginners in sheaf theory might think. It is in fact needed to prove e.g. that if $F$ is a sheaf and $U$, $V$ are two disjoint open sets, then $F(U\cup V)=F(U)\times F(V)$. This of course is used all the time, and the only way to prove it is via (1) which in turn is proved by considering the empty covering of $\emptyset$, as Dmitri says.

Comment: @Dmitri: I have given one specific example where I am arguing that it might be more sensible to set $0^0=0$. That is the only point I was trying to make: that I can think of *one* example. I also absolutely agree with you that it's easy to think of many more examples where it's sensible to set $0^0=1$. The reason I mentioned all this was simply because one example is more than no examples, and I cannot think of any examples *at* *all* when one should break some of the other conventions, e.g. det of the empty matrix.

Comment: @Kevin: Your example was about the function x∈[0,∞)↦0^x.  But what makes this function interesting enough?  Binomial theorem and power series are definitely interesting, but is there any interesting theorem that uses this function?

Comment: (2) is a really great example. One could think of $B/A$ is the pushout of $A \to B$ along $A \to 1$, and then it's clear what happens in the case $A = \emptyset$.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard: Defining $|f|$ as the smallest real number such that $f$ maps balls with radius $r$ into balls with radius $|f|r$, for all $r > 0$, should work for all cases, right?

Comment: $0^0=42$ is the convention I use.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, [but](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/sexy-vacuity#comment110448_45969) it's OK that the determinant of the $0\times0$ $0$ matrix is $1$, because it's also the $0\times0$ identity matrix.  :-)

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine : Can you elaborate somewhat on the $0\times0$ matrix? How does one encounter it or use it?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: The 0⨯0 matrix is the matrix of the identity operator on the zero vector space.  The zero vector space has an empty basis, so the matrix of the identity operator in this basis has size 0⨯0.  You use the 0⨯0 matrix in exactly the same manner as other matrices (keeping in mind that, as previously indicated, the empty sum is zero, the empty product is one, etc.).

Comment: @DmitriPavlov : Do any unexpected or interesting results follow from the use of the $0\times0$ matrix?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Not that I am aware of, at least if interesting implies nontrivial.  All the results work as expected (which is good) and the usual constructions work normally, e.g., the determinant of the 0⨯0 matrix is 1.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov : The determinant of a matrix is a sum of products. When the number of terms in a sum is $0,$ then the sum is $0.$ Why would that not apply here?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: It does not apply here because the number of terms in the sum is 1, not 0.  The sum is indexed by permutations of sets with n elements, and there is exactly one permutation of the empty set, namely, the empty permutation.  The number of such permutations is n!, and 0! = 1.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov : I see.

Comment: @user3840170, users are entitled to have the content of their posts as they please (I guess with certain rare exceptions that are up to a moderator, not individual users, to enforce), so, if a user [rolls back](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/45969/5) your [revision](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/45969/4) to their post, then you should not [re-make that revision](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/45969/6).

Comment: @LSpice: No offence taken (or meant), I just was (and still is) rather confused by these suggestions, since I do not understand your claims that somehow my code is not valid TeX.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/interesting-examples-of-vacuous-void-entities/45969#comment1139435_45969), I deleted a longer comment now that I think I understand your point better.  I indeed worded my suggestion in a way that suggested that something like `$x∈X$` is not valid TeX.  That is wrong, and I did not mean that.  I think that `$x∈X$` is less common than `$x\in X$`, and that the latter approach has advantages, but I did not mean to suggest that the former was invalid, and I apologise.

Comment: @LSpice: I see, it must be the [discussion on Meta from 2013](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/624/on-an-answer-containing-pre-formatted-text).  However, details are important and the context of that discussion is considerably different: it talks about Unicode's Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols, which are not present in many fonts, so their (direct) use may present a difficulty for users.  In contrast, both TeX and MathJax interpret ∈ and \in identically inside \$...\$ and would always produce identical results.  (That is to say, ∈ is parsed by MathJax as \in on a syntactic level.)

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1139446), this is not quite literally true.  I don't know what capacities were added when, but I believe Knuth's original TeX would simply choke on, or silently ignore, ∈ in the source.  I think it is only with [XeTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX) that TeX compilers started to become Unicode aware.  But, more importantly, in the context `\def\in{\text{bang!}}…`, `\in` and `∈` are interpreted differently.  Of course that particular use would be absurd, but systematically using Unicode does remove some of TeX's flexibility as a macro language.

Comment: @LSpice: The behavior you just described is MathJax-specific.  (It does work as I described in plain TeX and LaTeX.  For the original TeX engine, you need to use the appropriate Unicode package.)  In fact, from a long-term perspective, I would advise _against_ using such tricks (such as redefining predefined macros) in MathJax, since there is no guarantee that MathJax will continue to honor such tricks in the future.  Just to give an example how certain MathJax tricks were broken, not so long ago, a TeX macro would “leak” between posts, and some users exploited it.  This behavior is now gone.

Comment: @LSpice: For example, using \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} instead of unicode-math (with the ordinary TeX engine instead of LuaTeX) gives the result I described above.  (You also need amsmath for \text{...}.)

Answer (score 32):

If you've ever written code to convert an integer into a string of decimal digits, you may have come to the conclusion that the integer 0 should map not to the string *0*, but to the empty string instead. Most algorithms I've seen need to introduce a kludge to make 0 come out right. After all, when we write 0 we are violating the usual rule of "no leading zeros".

A nice, natural recursive expression of the conversion process is

```
def itoa(n):
  if n==0: return ""
  return itoa(n/10) + chr(ord('0') + n%10)
```

which can be thought of as 
*The string representation of an integer consists of its leading digits (n/10) followed by its last digit (n%10).*

Trying to fix this by returning "0" instead of "" would result in everything getting a superfluous leading zero.

On the other hand writing *0* as the empty string would be rather annoying.

Comment:     def itoa(n):
      (n>9 ? itoa(n/10) : "") + chr(ord('0') + n%10)



Comment: Ancients would write 0 as an empty string.

Comment: In fact "" is one symbol more than needed compared to 0 :D On top of that, this second symbol is a duplication of the first, which makes it even more superfluous

Comment: In the same way, the 0 polynomial should really be of degree -1.

Comment: Isn't the 0 polynomial of degree $-\infty$?

Comment: Just a minor comment: this is the example that was used to first teach me recursion.

Answer (score 31):

The usual axiomatizations of set theory (without
urelements) mean that every set in the entire set-theoretic
universe is ultimately built from copies of the emptyset,
in complex empty-box-in-a-box-in-a-box constructions.

Comment: Amazing. I gave this answer (in terms of ordinals) four hours before and ot one vote only !

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had't noticed the second part of your answer! Since  the observation applies in ZFC not only to ordinals, but to all sets, I'll leave this answer up.

Comment: In a similar vein, Conway's theory of Games (which include the Surreal Numbers) gets quite a lot of mileage out of considering the "empty game" in which neither player has any move at all.  Every game can be considered as a built from it, just as in Set theory.

Answer (score 28):

What about the two orientations of a point?
$$*$$

*(Pro trivialogia)*. I'd like to add some general remarks about the question you raised in the comment below, which seems to me a question of general interest. I see at least three general good reasons why it is worth dealing with trivial cases of mathematical notions.

- *Sometimes we simply do not know whether $x$ is a trivial object*. Even if our main interest is in non-trivial cases, in the course of a proof or a computation we deal with unknown objects $x,\, y\dots,$ that may possibly degenerate. Therefore, we would like theorems, methods, rules, to hold with the minimum of assumptions, avoiding special separate treatments for degenerate cases (think to some classifications into unnecessary special cases, for algebraic equations, used at the beginning of algebra).
- *Abstraction*. It is a great feature of modern mathematics the ability of translating a complicated notion belonging to a simple setting, into a simple notion belonging to a possibly more complicated setting (in many abstract contexts the cost of this operation is zero). Example: a limit or a colimit in a category, and in fact any universal construction, is just a zero-object in a suitable category (as an application, Freyd's theorem about existence of adjoint functors, &c.)
- *Constructions and proofs by induction.* As soon as the induction step from $n$ to $n+1$ is suitably clarified, the validity of the general fact is reduced to that of the trivial case, that becomes the heart of the whole story. So for instance, the very reason of some facts about spheres is some (trivial, but important) fact about $\mathbb{S}^0$. This is of course also the case of constructions and operations with orientations.

Comment: Talking about a point $p$ as a connected real manifold $M=${p} of dimension $0$. It has two canonical orientations, $+1$ and $-1$, the generators of the top-degree exterior power $\Lambda^{top}(T_p M)=\mathbb{R}^1$. It seems to me another instance of a trivial case of a mathematical notion, as interesting and useful as the other ones (and slightly paradoxical as well). 

Comment: And this is essential when considering 1-dimensional framed bordism.

Comment: I don't know what a 1-dimensional framed bordism is, but I'm glad someone mentioned that there's a (nontrivial?) reason to think about the concept.

Comment: I used to work with a notion of orientation (in a context of Fredholm pairs and Fredholm operators) and trivial cases where actually the key point of the whole story. But this question seems of general interest, so I add some remark on this point.

Comment: I wasn't convinced about orienting points -- as $GL(0)/SL(0)$ has one component, not two -- until I hit the statement "If $A = B\oplus C$, orienting any two uniquely determines an orientation on the third."

Comment: I had similar thoughts to Allen, but I resolved them like this.  More natural than SL(n) is "BSL(n)", the homotopy fiber of the determinant map BGL(n) --> BGL(1).  For n>0 this is connected and indeed is homotopy equivalent with BSL(n), but for n=0 it's homotopically two points.

Comment: (And instead of GL(n)/SL(n) one takes the homotopy fiber of "BSL(n)" --> BGL(n).)

Comment: Yes. $BSO(n)$ is a $2$-sheeted cover of $BO(n)$ even when $n=0$. (But to make sense of this you might have to think of $SO(0)$ as a groupoid, not a group.)

Answer (score 27):

$\bigcap \emptyset = V$

Unfortunately, I have read more than one philosophical comment on the "set theoretic depth" of this logical triviality.

Comment: In some topology book I read that it's redundant to say the whole space is an open set after you've said the intersection of any finite set of open sets is open.

Comment: Peter, this is technically incorrect, since it doesn't make sense to take the intersection of two sets not embedded in a set.  Indeed, category theory points us to the following: $\bigcap \emptyset=*$. That is, the limit over the trivial diagram is the terminal object.  

Comment: Indeed, this is a special case of Eivind's answer! That is, the intersection is a special case of the fibre product of injections, which is simply the product in the overcategory. If we're extremely careful, we don't get something undefined like "the entire universe", which cannot be a set unless we look at the category of injections over a set (in which case, the terminal object will be that set)! Indeed, when people say "assume we have a universal set", they exactly mean to say that every set they want to use is a subset of this universal set.  It's nothing more than slicing!

Comment: Certainly, there is nothing wrong with stating this in a class set theory like NBG, where it is correct. And you do not have to take the intersection of any two sets, since we are talkning about the empty set. Moreover, any two sets can be embedded in a set- the set containing exactly these two sets. 


Comment: @Michael: Certainly you want the limit of a small diagram into the category of sets to be a set, no?

Comment: Formally there's nothing wrong. The way $\bigcap$ is usually defined (in the language of set theory) is  $(\forall x) x \in \bigcap A \Leftrightarrow ((\forall y) y \in A \Rightarrow x \in y)$

And, of course vacuously $(\forall x)(\forall y) y \in \emptyset \Rightarrow x \in y$.

Comment: A fairly closely related example is the fact that every complete lattice has a largest and a smallest element. These are the infimum and the supremum of the empty set, respectively.

Comment: @Harry: the basic POV of traditional set-theory based foundations considers all sets as once-and-for-all embedded in the class $V$.  So then we really can consider intersections among them, and we do get $\bigcap \empty = V$.  We're taking the limit of $\empty$ not in the category $\mathbf{Sets}$ (which gives $*$, as you say), but in partially-ordered class of subsets of $V$ (or equivalently, in $V$ itself ordered by $\subseteq$).  Several authors in Algebraic Set Theory have considered the connection between these two structures.

Comment: @Peter: Bourbaki proves in _Théorie des Ensembles_ that $\bigcap \emptyset$ is not a formula defining a set (i.e., the relation (formula) is not "collectivisante") (and indeed, I believe this is provable in traditional ZFC as well).  

Comment: In particular, since the axioms of power-set, subset, and union allow us to take the union of a family of subsets of something already known to be a set, say $X$, and the intersection is defined to be the complement  of the union of the complements in $X$.  

Comment: @Harry: Your proposed definition of intersection sounds like something from category theory rather than from traditional set theory.  In the context of the latter, do you find something wrong with saying $x \in \cap A$ iff $\forall a \in A\, x \in a$?

Comment: The standard set theories are ZFC and NBG. When talking about sets without any qualifier, one talks about them. The usual definition of an intersection is the one given by Peter. That taking intersections over the empty set gives you the class of all sets is something you can prove in NBG. In ZFC, there are no classes, so the intersection over the empy set doesn't give you something in the theory. V is not a set, and this might be what Bourbaki was refering too. But even in ZFC, one can translate the property of being "in the intersection of the empty set" to a property that aplies to all sets

Comment: Michael, I don't understand the allure of being able to get out of the theory of sets by ordinary operations.  If a theory proves that $\bigap \emptyset=V$, then it is a problem with the definition of $\bigcap$.  

Comment: Harry, for a moment ignore my ZFC "shorthand" of writing $\bigcap$ and $V$ (which I blatantly used to make it more, well, sexy). Instead, just look at the last formula in my previous comment. For any set theory (first order logic, signature $\{ \in \}$ etc) which proves an empty set exists, this theorem is (vacuously) true.

That's all I'm saying (and as I said, I do not believe it is deep, it's just classical logic). Feel free to drop by my office (4826) if you have further questions.

Comment: To return to Michael's first comment, the non-philosophical (and useful) statement is that the intersection of an empty family of subsets of a set X is X itself. This is why we define X to be open in X for a topological space X, because it is a finite intersection.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/posts/comments/110852), why is $\bigcap \emptyset = V$ more offensive than $\inf \emptyset = \top$?

Answer (score 25):

The terminal object of a category is the product over the empty set of objects.

Comment: That's exactly the answer I would have given :-P

Comment: Indeed, probably every answer here is this one in disguise.

Answer (score 25):

I regard "negative thinking" in category theory as an example of cool vacuity: see e.g. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/negative+thinking. As category theory is not set theory, such vacuity does not necessarily involve the empty set directly, but the same principle of backwards generalization is used.

The fact that a set is uniquely determined by its elements (i.e., has no additional structure beyond the equality relation between its elements) is summarized by saying that a (-1)-category is a truth value: a morphism between two elements in a set is either true (the elements are the same) or false (they are not). So the morphisms in a 0-category (a set) are (-1)-categories (either true or false), just as the morphisms in a (1-)category are 0-categories (sets). This admits generalizations to situations where "truth" is a more subtle concept (e.g. parameter dependent).

Answer (score 24):

The determinant of the $0\times 0$ matrix is $1$. First of all, it's the only way to make determinant of a direct sum of matrices be a product of determinants. Second, it is the sum of $0!$ terms each of which is a product of $0$ factors.

Comment: Third, with this convention, Dogson's condensation formula for the determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix boils down to the usual formula.

Comment: I guess I have to add that the sign of the permutation of $0$ elements is $1$, because the number of inversions is even.

Comment: @LevBorisov, also because it's the identity element of $S_0$, and the sign map is a homomorphism.

Comment: It's also the (empty) product of the eigenvalues of the $0 \times 0$ matrix.

Comment: And the volume of the 0-dimensional space consisting of a single point. :)

Comment: Also, the determinant of an endomorphism of a free module $M$ of rank n is the scalar which gives the resulting endomorphism of the nth exterior power of $M$. When $n$ is zero this is clearly $1$. (The $0$th exterior power of any module is (naturally) isomorphic to the standard free module of rank $1$.

Answer (score 23):

When defining a **topology**.

Do not say

> the intersection of any two open sets is open

but instead say

> any finite intersection of open sets is open

That way, you assert in particular that the empty intersection of open sets (i.e. the whole space) is open.

Of course we also postulate

> an arbitrary union of open sets is open

telling us that the empty union (i.e. $\varnothing$) is open.

**similar**
Caratheodory's "Method I" for constructing an outer measure $m^*$ in a set $X$ starting from a set-function $E : \mathcal E \to [0,+\infty]$  is done like this:

> $m^*(A) = \inf\sum_{i=1}^\infty E(A_i)$ where the inf is over all sequences $(A_i)_{i=1}^\infty \subseteq \mathcal E$ such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \supseteq A$.

But then we have to include artificial hypotheses like "$\mathcal E$ covers the whole space" and "$\varnothing \in \mathcal E$ and $E(\varnothing) = 0$".
But instead we should do it like this

> $m^*(A) = \inf\sum_{F \in \mathcal F}E(F)$ where the inf is over all countable collections $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathcal E$ such that $\bigcup_{F \in \mathcal F} F \supseteq A$

Then: we need not postulate that $\mathcal E$ covers $X$, since if there is no countable $\mathcal F$ with $\bigcup_{F \in \mathcal F} F \supseteq A$, then we simply get $m^*(A) = \inf\varnothing = +\infty$.  And for the empty set, we have (possibly among others) the empty cover for $\varnothing$, so that $m^*(\varnothing) \le 0$, the empty sum.  So we get $m^*(\varnothing) = 0$ even if (for example) $E$ is identically $+\infty$.

Comment: Both Carathéodory-type definitions agree on the meaning of $m^*(A)$ if $\mathcal E$ does not contain a countable cover of $A$.

Comment: The empty cover is not countable though

Comment: @JohannesHahn ... I consider $\varnothing$ to be a countable set (not uncountable).

Answer (score 21):

'Silly' but I like them anyways:

$$\prod_{y\in\emptyset}\left(\sum_{x\in \emptyset}x\right)=1,$$

and

$$\sum_{y\in\emptyset}\left(\prod_{x\in \emptyset}x\right)=0.$$

But, careful:

$$\sum_{S\subseteq \emptyset}\prod_{x\in\emptyset}x=1,$$

and

$$\prod_{S\subseteq \emptyset}\sum_{x\in\emptyset}x=0.$$

Answer (score 21):

The ‘divides’ relation $\mid$ should properly be called a ‘has-a-multiple-of’ relation and defined without any reference to division as

$$ a \mid b \iff \exists c: ac = b $$

This definition implies $\forall a: a \mid 0$ (including $0 \mid 0$) and $\forall a: 0 \mid a \Longrightarrow a = 0$. And over the non-negative integers in particular, the relation becomes a complete lattice, where the infimum is the GCD and the supremum is the LCM.

This comes up as the inductive base case when computing the GCD/LCM of arbitrary sets of numbers. Sometimes people say that the GCD of no numbers doesn’t exist, but when the GCD is defined as the infimum of the $\mid$ relation, it becomes perfectly natural to set it to 0 at the empty set.

This can be taken advantage of in other mathematical definitions.  The characteristic of a ring $R$ is commonly defined as ‘the smallest non-zero natural number $k$ such that $\forall x \in R: \sum^k x = 0_R$, or 0 if there is no such number’.  Knowing the above, however, we can reformulate the definition thus:

$$ \operatorname{char}(R) := \operatorname{gcd}\, \left\{ k \in \mathbb N : \forall x \in R : \sum^k x = 0_R \right\}$$

which does not require separately considering zero and non-zero cases.

---

Somewhat related, though perhaps too silly to mention: division by zero is undefined. However, *remainder* of division by zero is not: it is simply the identity function.

One way to see this is to observe that no matter how Euclidean division by zero $(a \mapsto a \div 0)$ is defined, there is only one way to define the remainder $a \bmod 0$ such that the identity

$$ (a \div b) \cdot b + (a \bmod b) = a $$

is maintained. (Of course, if $a \div 0$ is defined, it will necessarily break the usual property that $|a - (a \div b) \cdot b| < |b|$ for every $a$ and $b$ where it is defined.)

Another is to notice that $(a \mapsto a \bmod b) : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb {Z}$ is a unity-preserving homomorphism of rings. For $b = 0$, the codomain becomes $\mathbb{Z}/0\mathbb {Z} = \mathbb{Z}$, and the requirement that $1 \bmod 0 = 1$ forces the function to be the identity function.  Setting $a \bmod 0 = a$ also agrees with the property that $b \mid a$ if and only if $a \bmod b = 0$.

Comment: Another reason to say that the gcd of the empty set is 0 is that in Euclid's algorithm, the gcd always remains the same from one step to the next ($\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a,b-a)$) and it stops at $0$ and you then have $\gcd(c,0)=c,$ so that $0$ is an identity element for this binary operation. $\qquad$

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand "GCD is defined as the infimum of the $\mid$ relation", but I *think* it should be *supremum*:  $\gcd(S) = \sup_\mid \operatorname{CD}_S$, where $\operatorname{CD}_S = \{n \in \mathbb Z_{\ge 0} \mathrel| \forall s \in S,\,n \mid s\}$.  Indeed, since $\operatorname{CD}_\emptyset = \mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$, the infimum would be $1$, not $0$.  Or maybe you meant to take the infimum of something else?

Comment: $\operatorname{gcd}(S) := \inf_\mid(S)$. Your restatement relies on the fact that the infimum of a set is the supremum of the set of its lower bounds.

Comment: Oh!  Somehow that way of thinking had never occurred to me.

Answer (score 19):

The [Generalized Continuum
Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#The_generalized_continuum_hypothesis)
is the assertion that $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$ for all infinite
cardinals $\kappa$, or in other words that the power set of
a set of size $\kappa$ has the next larger cardinal size
above $\kappa$.

If we consider all cardinals, rather than only the infinite
cardinals, then the two provable instances of this equation
occur in the following vacuous and near-vacuous facts:

- The power set of a set with $0$ members has $1$
  member.
- The power set of a set with $1$ member has $2$ members.

All other instances of $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$, finite or
infinite, are either false or independent of ZFC.

Comment: I heard once that at a Logic Colloquium talk in Berkeley
when Foreman or Woodin was speaking on their theorem
concerning the consistency that the GCH fails everywhere,
the speaker wrote "$2^\kappa\neq\kappa^+$ for all $\kappa$"
on the blackboard. Leo Harrington reportedly went silently
up to the blackboard, adding the words "except $\kappa=0$
or $1$."

Answer (score 17):

Zero is a limit ordinal, because it is the union of its elements.

Transfinite induction has two canonical statements.  The "strong" statement, 
$$
(\forall \alpha)((\forall \beta)((\beta<\alpha) \rightarrow P(\beta)) \rightarrow P(\alpha))\rightarrow (\forall \alpha)P(\alpha),
$$
doesn't split anything into cases.  The version used most frequently in proofs says that any property preserved under unions and successors holds for all ordinals.  Zero should rarely be a special case.

Also, "limit ordinals" should totally be called "colimit ordinals".  The term "limit ordinal" refers to limit points in the order topology, thus excluding zero, but this is silly.

Comment: Category theory does not have a monopoly on the word "limit".

Comment: True :)
I just think things should have names and definitions that reflect the way they're most often used.

Answer (score 15):

The empty product in a group $G$ is the unit of $G$. This is the only way to avoid mistake in calculations.

Set theory begins by the construction of finite ordinals. The first one is $\emptyset$ and is denoted $0$. The next one is $\{\emptyset\}$, which is not empty ! It is denoted $1$. More generally, every finite ordinal is defined only in terms of the empty set recursively: $n+1:=n\cup\{ n \}$. Physicists (or administrators, politicians, whoever is asked to fund mathematics) might find this pedantic, but it is actually powerful.

Comment: The idea of empty products and empty sums seems to make sense only if the operation involved is associative, and then whenever there's an identity element.  When asked why the product of no numbers is 1, one can answer that multiplying something by no numbers just leaves it fixed, so it's the same as multiplying it by 1.  But you need associativity for that to make sense.

Comment: ....and so that's why it works in all groups.

Comment: This was discussed in a question on math.stackexchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6832/why-is-two-to-the-power-of-zero-equal-to-binary-one 

Comment: Related to this, one can combine the closure, associativity, and identity axioms of a group by requiring that a group be closed under all finite ordered products (including the empty product), together with a unified associativity axiom $\prod_{\alpha \in A} \prod_{\beta \in B_\alpha} g_\beta = \prod_{\beta \in \biguplus_{\alpha \in A} B_\alpha} g_\beta$ (maintaining the ordering of the index sets in the obvious manner), as well as an axiom that a unary product of a group element $g$ is equal to $g$.

Answer (score 15):

Zsbán Ambrus brings up an interesting example in the comments: the degree of the zero polynomial.  The first time I was told about this issue I was told that it is largely a matter of convention.  Well, maybe.  Here is some evidence suggesting that $\deg 0 = \infty$:

- The most basic one: the zero polynomial has infinitely many roots in an algebraic closure.
- <strike>If one wants the degree of a polynomial to be a [valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra)), then we must define $\deg 0 = \infty$.  This is the unique choice consistent with the requirements that $\deg fg = \deg f + \deg g$ and $\deg (f+g) \ge \text{min}(\deg f, \deg g)$, and it is necessary in order to make the corresponding [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Fields) nondegenerate.</strike>
- <strike>One way to say the above geometrically when $F = \mathbb{C}$ is that the degree should describe the order of the pole of $f$ at infinity on the Riemann sphere.  The function $0$ decays faster than the reciprocal of any polynomial in the neighborhood of infinity.  In fact, the sequence of functions $x^n$ converges uniformly to it in a neighborhood of infinity as $n \to \infty$.</strike>
- <strike>Another way to say the above is that, in the natural topology on $F[[x]]$, we have $x^n \to 0$.  This can be appreciated even if you are, for example, a combinatorialist, because it allows you to say natural things about generating functions like $\frac{1 - x^n}{1 - x} \to \frac{1}{1 - x}$ as $n \to \infty$.</strike>
- One can also define the degree of $f$ as $[F[x]/(f(x)) : F]$, in which case again we find that $\deg 0 = \infty$.  This is just a fancier version of the first reason.

**Edit:**  As James Borger points out, the middle ideas are mistaken.  Corrected, they actually suggest that $\deg 0 = -\infty$:

- $\deg 0 = -\infty$ is the unique choice consistent with the requirements that $\deg fg = \deg f + \deg g$ and $\deg (f + g) \le \max(\deg f, \deg g)$.  With this definition, $|f| = 2^{\deg f}$ is now an absolute value.
- Geometrically, when $F = \mathbb{C}$ the function $0$ has a zero of infinite order at infinity, hence a pole of order $-\infty$.
- The relevant local ring here is really $F[[ \frac{1}{x} ]]$, and in the natural topology on this ring we have $\frac{1}{x^n} \to 0$.
- Another reason to like this definition is that it gives a uniform statement of the division algorithm on $F[x]$.

Comment: I was taught $0$ has no degree.

Comment: @Jeff: certainly one can make the case for this, but I don't remember a particular compelling argument in this direction.

Comment: I will definitely adopt this convention forever!

Comment: Dear Qiaochu, I'm not sure I agree with all this. First, it's not true that $\deg(f+g)\geq \min(\deg f,\deg g)$. Take $f=x^{100}$, $g=1-x^{100}$. It is true that $\deg(f+g)\leq \max(\deg f, \deg g)$. Second, 0 has a zero of infinite order at $x=\infty$, and hence a pole of order $-\infty$ there. Third, it seems beside the point to take convergence in $F[[x]]$, which is the local ring at $x=0$. I think the local ring at infinity $F[[x^{-1}]]$ is more relevant, and then $x^n \to 0$ as $n\to-\infty$. So I'd prefer to set $\deg 0 = -\infty$.

Comment: @James: whoops.  You make a good point.  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: $-\infty$ crops up here (and in other places such as the dimension of the empty set) because it is the supremum of the empty set: in this case it is the supremum of the set of powers with nonzero coefficients.

Comment: So it's not true that if you differentiate a polynomial then its degree goes down by 1? (I suppose that even if you set deg(0)=-1 that rule is violated, so this isn't such a strong argument.)

Comment: @gowers: that rule is also false in positive characteristic, so I don't think it's universal enough to count as evidence either way.

Comment: When $-\infty$ goes down by one, it does not change.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie:  The fight wasn't about differentiating zero itself, but about passing from a non-zero constant to zero.

Answer (score 14):

Recall that an abstract simplicial complex consists of a family of finite sets $K\subseteq 2^V$ such that $\sigma\in K$ and $\tau\subseteq\sigma$ implies $\tau\in K$. (Sometimes it is also assumed that $\{v\}\in K$ for all $v\in V$.) Elements of $K$ are called faces of $K$. Dimension of a face is its cardinality minus 1.

According to the above definition, if $S\not=\emptyset$, then the empty set $\emptyset$ is a face of the complex (of dimension $-1$, since it has $0$ elements). Applying the usual definition of simplicial homology gives us what is called reduced homology, which is often much better-behaved than the nonreduced one (obtained when we forget about the empty face).

In this context it is important to distinguish between the *empty simplicial complex* $K_e=\{\emptyset\}$ and the *void simplicial complex* $K_v=\{\}$, which may be understood as the $(-1)$-sphere and the $(-1)$-disk. (In particular $H_{-1}(K_e)=\mathbb{Z}$, $H_n(K_e)=0$ for all $n\not=-1$, and $H_m(K_v)=0$ for all $m$.)

Comment: I would change the definition to avoid having to view the void complex as a simplicial complex.  The $-1$-sphere on the other hand is a perfectly decent space, defined as the points in $\mathbb{R}^0$ at distance 1 from the origin, a sort of boundary of the 0-disk.

Answer (score 11):

One is not a prime number, but zero is!  It's different than the other prime numbers in $\mathbb{Z}$, though, because it has height zero rather than height one.

Zero is prime in any integral domain.  Remember that the trivial ring is *not* an integral domain.

Comment: I don't find this convincing. Yes, zero generates a prime ideal, which is an element of Spec, etc. But "prime number" has a specific definition that excludes $0$.

Answer (score 8):

I'm always amused (and unpopular for it) when mathematicians claim that some terminology or notation is "true" rather than "convention", as if there is some God of Mathematics out there who hands us definitions that us mere humans are forbidden to tamper with.  Actually *all* mathematical notation is convention.

We could, if we agreed as a body to do so, define "$m+n$" to mean what it used to mean, unless $m=n=1$ in which case it means 3. It isn't forbidden, because we invented "$+$"; it belongs to us and we can choose what it means.  We won't do that, though, not because it is *wrong* according to some objective source of truth, but because it would cause us a whole heap of trouble. For example we would have to rewrite a huge number of theorems to add exceptional cases, and we hate exceptional cases. It isn't a question of "truth" since all of modern mathematics could be correctly stated using the new definition.

In the same way, we *choose* to set the empty product equal to 1, and the empty sum equal to  0, because those are the *conventions* that make our symbol manipulations so much easier and simpler than any alternative conventions would make them. It isn't really different, except in degree, to excluding 1 from being a prime. We do that because otherwise we would have to spend all day writing "let $p$ be a prime other than 1".  Qualitatively the reason is the same: we like our theorems to be cleaner, with fewer preconditions and fewer subcases. Simplicity and generality is a fundamental aesthetic of mathematics.

Comment: We mathematicians also seem to be hung up on repeatability and logical as well as otber forms of consistency.  Why are we so hidebound, I wonder?

Comment: How about [grue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_riddle_of_induction) primes?

Comment: While it's certainly true that definitions cannot be true (or false), I think that it is meaningful to distinguish among different types of conventions.  For example, I think that there is a difference between the convention "the empty product equals 1" and the convention "$\mathbb N$ contains $0$" (or the opposite of the latter convention, if that's the one you use).  Perhaps "forced by consistency" (or, even more explicitly, "forced by consistency with …") is better than "true"?

Comment: I don't think it's that we want our theorems to be cleaner. I think it's that the theorems (and the proof ideas) are what we *really* care about. We want them to be nice. The axioms are largely just a way to support the theorems. We develop axiom systems and theories (in the sense of a body of work) to support the theorems we care about. If the axioms don't give us the theorems we want, then we change the axioms. Of course, one person's axioms are another's theorems. Example: ring theorists have studied "general rings", but some (many?) algebraic geometers (ok, me) stick to rings with $1$...

Answer (score 7):

Let $\bigotimes_{i \in I} M_i$ denote the tensor product of $R$-modules $M_i$. Then $\bigotimes_{i \in \emptyset} M_i$ is $R$.

(Reason: $\prod_{i \in \emptyset} M_i$ is the terminal object in the category of sets (see the answer of Eivind Dahl), i.e. a point, and multilinear maps on this to $N$ are just elements of $N$, i.e. homomorphisms $R \to N$.)

Another one: I know this is really silly and already contained somehow in the other answers, but anyway:

$$\prod_{i \in \emptyset} 0 = 1$$

Comment: It makes if you consider what it would mean for a function be "0-linear".  The empty product is as a module isomorphic to 0, but if we want to consider multilinear functions, we're not considering it as a module; as a set it's $\{()\}$.  So we have functions from a one-element set, i.e. just any function, with the requirement that they be "0-linear", i.e. linear in all of the 0 arguments, which is a trivial requirement!  So it does work after all.

Comment: This can be motivated either by the fact that tensor products represent multilinear maps, or (as per another answer) the fact that *\otimes* is an associative, unital operation, so “$k$-ary tensor product” with $k=0$ must give the *unit* object for $\otimes$. (All up to coherent natural isomorphism, of course!) 

Comment: Or, to make it even more vacuous: it is a particular case of the fact that the composition of the zero amount of endofunctors is the identity functor...

Answer (score 7):

Pfister's local–global theorem has an interesting "vacuous" instance:

Remember that quadratic forms over a field $F$ of characteristic $\neq 2$ are diagonalizable, and hence a nondegenerate quadratic form can be represented by a sequence $\langle a_1, \dotsc, a_m \rangle$ of elements $a_i \in F^*$.

One can "add" diagonal quadratic forms by declaring
$\langle a_1, \dotsc, a_m \rangle \oplus \langle b_1, \dotsc, b_k \rangle :=\langle a_1, \dotsc, a_m, b_1, \dotsc, b_k \rangle$ and one can multiply quadratic forms with natural numbers by declaring $n\cdot\langle a_1, \dotsc, a_m \rangle:=\underbrace{\langle a_1, \dotsc, a_m \rangle\oplus \dotsb \oplus \langle a_1, \dotsc, a_m \rangle}_{n \text{ times}}$.

If "$<$" is an ordering on $F$ (compatible with $+$ and $\cdot$), then to a quadratic form $f=\langle a_1, \dotsc, a_m\rangle$ one can assign its signature $\sigma(f)(<):=\#\{ a_i \mid 0 < a_i\} - \#\{a_i \mid a_i < 0\}$. That is, the signature is the number of positive minus the number of negative diagonal entries, according to the ordering "$<$".
One can show that this signature is independent of the choice of diagonalization.

Thus, if we denote by $X(F)$ the set of all orderings of $F$, from a fixed quadratic form $f$ we obtain a well-defined map $X(F)\to \mathbb{Z}$, ${<} \mapsto \sigma(f)(<)$.

**Pfister's local–global theorem** says something about how much the map $\sigma(f)$ determines $f$:

Let $f$, $g$ be quadratic forms of the same rank over a field $F$.
If $\sigma(f)=\sigma(g)$, then there exists $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^\ell\cdot f \cong 2^\ell \cdot g$ (i.e. the multiplied forms are isometric).
[The theorem says more, but this is the relevant part.]

When $F$ is not orderable at all (e.g. if $F$ is algebraically closed or of characteristic $>0$, or $F=\mathbb{Q}_p$), then $X(F)=\emptyset$. Therefore there exists only one map $S\colon X(F) \to \mathbb{Z}$, i.e. any two quadratic forms $f$, $g$ satisfy $\sigma(f)=\sigma(g)$. Thus, for a non-orderable field, any two quadratic forms have isometric multiples: $2^\ell\cdot f \cong 2^\ell \cdot g$ for some $\ell$.

I learned this from a wonderful expository note [Introduction to the real spectrum](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/realspectrum.pdf) by Pete L. Clark.

Answer (score 6):

The zero ring has [Krull dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) $-\infty$. Why? It was already explained why $\sup(\emptyset)=-\infty$ in [another answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/46150/2841), and the zero ring has no prime ideal chain, so that's it. Also notice that the proof of $\dim(A[T]) \geq \dim(A)+1$ works for every commutative ring $A$ (with equality for Noetherian $A$), including $A=0$. You cannot have $\dim(0)=0$ or even $\dim(0)=-1$ (Wikipedia states this as an option, which is absurd).

Accordingly, a commutative ring in which every prime ideal is maximal does not have to be of Krull dimension $0$. It is just $\leq 0$.

Comment: We have been missing you, Martin. Welcome back.

Answer (score 5):

The full rank factorization of the 3x2 zero matrix is  the product of a 3x0 matrix times a 0x2 matrix. There exist empty matrices with n>0 rows and 0 column. The 0x0 empty matrix is the only non nonsingular zero matrix.

Comment: Related to https://mathoverflow.net/a/157177.  (I could have sworn one of the answers here pointed to [de Boor - An empty exercise](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/122272.122273), which is even more related, but I can't find that answer.  EDIT:  Oh, it was a [comment by @Ramsay](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/interesting-examples-of-vacuous-void-entities#comment160966_46009).)

Answer (score 5):

A "convention" floating around in (co)homology theory is that given a space $X$ the quotient with the empty set is $X/\emptyset = X_+ = X \sqcup *.$ This seems rather arbitrary if one defines $X/A$ to be given by coequalizing the inclusion $A \subseteq X$ and a constant map $\smash{A \rightarrow * \underset{a}{\rightarrow} X}$ to some point $a \in A$.

But there is another possible definition: $X/A$ is the pushout
$$\begin{array}{cc}
   A & \rightarrow & X\\
   \downarrow & & \downarrow\\
   * & \rightarrow & X/A
\end{array}$$
Setting $A=\emptyset$ we can recover $X/\emptyset = X \sqcup * = X_+$. In particular this specializes to the [counterintuitive identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190193/wedge-sum-of-an-empty-set-of-spaces) $\emptyset / \emptyset = *$.

Comment: Should "a constant map to some point of $A$" be understood as "a constant map, on $A$, to some point of the image of $A$ in $X$"?  Otherwise I have trouble understanding how to co-equalise two such maps.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. I hope my edit makes this clearer. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 3):

> *Let $p,q$ be Hilbert space projections. If $pq+qp$ is a non-zero projection then, where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio, $$\lVert pq\rVert=\frac{1}{\varphi}.$$*

It follows very quickly from [Walters - Anticommutator Norm Formula for Projection Operators](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00699)… but is it vacuous? [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4290981/19352) to [Is $p q + q p$
ever a projection?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288879/is-pqqp-ever-a-projection) on MSE seemed to resolve the issue but has an issue.

Answer (score 2):

**A** The empty set is a covering map of any topological space.  More generally, a covering map needn't be surjective (although many books claim just that). For example the inclusion of a closed and open subset of a space is a covering. Strangely, I would argue  that this entails that the empty topological space, although connected, is not simply connected.

**B** Dually, given a field $K$, the zero algebra over $K$ is diagonal and in particular étale: the morphism of affine schemes $\varnothing  \to \operatorname{Spec}(K) $ is étale. In the same vein, a  nonzero constant polynomial over $K$ is separable (its nonexistent roots in an algebraic closure of $K$ are certainly distinct) . We  may then say without any exception that the $K$-algebra   $K[X]/(f(X))$ is  étale iff $f(X)$ is a separable polynomial.

Comment: Agreed, except that I strongly prefer not to call the empty space connected. How many components does it have?

Comment: Dear Tom, it has one component, like all connected spaces. Bourbaki (and many textbooks) consider that the empty space is connected; but on the other hand a mathematician for whom I have enormous affection and admiration thinks, like you, that the empty set is not connected. So I suggest peaceful coexistence between the two points of view. Or maybe we should adopt the motto "don't ask, don't tell" on this question of connectedness? 

Comment: If we assume disjoint union is additive on the number of connected components, then the empty space should have zero connected components.  I think this should correspond to the usual distinction between primes (connected spaces) and units (empty spaces) in situations where we have unique factorization.

Comment: Dear Scott: I  thought of zero connected components just after posting (as usual!) and  your excellent arguments convince me that this is the better point of view .

Comment: The empty space IS connected, and (but) has zero connected components:
the connected components are the equivalence classes of the relation on the set defined by lying in a common connected subset. The partition in connected components is the empty partition of the empty set, as in the question leading to this thread.

It is also simply connected in the sense of the theory of coverings: all of its coverings are trivial.


Comment: Dear ACL, I agree with you on the connectedness questions (Scott converted me on the zero number of components). But I still do not agree with simple-connectedness : if the empty space were simply-connected, wouldn't it be the universal covering of every space ?

Comment: @Georges and ACL: No, the empty space is by no means connected, because many theorems containing the word “connected” will fail if it is. For example, every manifold is the coproduct of a unique family of connected manifolds. A space is connected (in the appropriate sense) if and only if its π_0 is a one-element set. The π_0 of the empty space is empty. 

Comment: I would define a space X to be connected if, whenever it is expressed as a topological disjoint sum (i.e., coproduct) of spaces, one of the summands is X itself.  This leads to the conclusion that the empty space is not connected, because t is the topological disjoint sum of zero spaces.  (Analogously, I would define a positive integer to be prime if, whenever it is expressed as a product, it equals one of the factors.  That makes the empty product, 1, not prime.)

Comment: @Dmitri: All of this is a matter of convention. Many theorems apply to non-empty connected sets (think of the union of two connected sets whose intersection is connected...).

The empty manifold is the coproduct of the empty family...

Higher homotopy suggests that it is reasonable not to view the empty set as connected. Anyway, homotopy theory is essentially a theory of pointed spaces, and pointed spaces are not empty.

Comment: @Georges: In the category of spaces, there can't be a universal covering.

The theory of universal covering is a theory of pointed spaces: A pointed cover (Y,y) of a pointed space (X,x) is a universal covering if, for any pointed cover (Z,z) of (X,x), there is a unique X-morphism $f:(Y,y)\rightarrow (Z,z)$ of pointed covers.




Comment: There is a weakly universal covering, though: it can be dscribed as the colimit over fundamental groupoid with values the usual pointed universal covers. This all assumes these covers exist, which requires conditions on the base etc etc..

Comment: Dear ACL: yes, I also like the idea of restricting the notion of (universal) covering space to pointed spaces. I vaguely remember reading that our Overlords (Deligne et al.) are quite categorical on this point. 

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Wow, this is a very concise definition! We could also say that on a connected space every continuous function should be constant of some value (i.e. factors over $\{\star\}$). But functions on $\emptyset$ have no value.

Comment: Oups, I meant continuous functions into discrete spaces, aka locally constant functions.

Comment: "[Quite categorical](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/interesting-examples-of-vacuous-void-entities#comment110897_46010)", heh.

Comment: Glad you noticed, dear @LSpice!

Answer (score 2):

$\forall M\in\mathsf{Set}\setminus\{\emptyset\} : \emptyset^M=\emptyset$, but

$\forall N\in\mathsf{Set}: N^\emptyset = \{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: $\ldots\,$and for cardinal numbers $a\ne0$ and $b,$ you have $0^a=0$ and $b^0=1. \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is not serious, but then in a sense none of the examples in this thread are.

Jordan decomposition represents every operator on a finite-dimensional space in a unique way as $S+N$ where $S$ is a diagonalizable operator, $N$ is a nilpotent operator, and $SN=NS$.

The Jordan decomposition of the zero operator is $0+0$. It thus is the only operator which is diagonalizable and nilpotent at the same time.

Similarly, the zero Lie algebra is the only one which is both semisimple and nilpotent. And one might also argue that it is *not* simple. Or is it?...

Comment: The question asks for other examples of non-trivial and interesting mathematics arising out of seemingly trivial instances of vacuity. So what is the non-trivial or interesting math arising from this one?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I accept your objection. In fact the reason I decided to add this was that only recently in my work this seemingly vacuous circumstance caused quite nontrivial additional considerations. Unfortunately they are too technical to even attempt telling about it here.

Comment: The proof will not fit into the margin.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Exactly ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose another example would be those proofs by induction in which you don't need a basis, although no nice examples come to mind instantly.  Here I mean proofs in which you show that if $P(m)$ for all $m < n$, then $P(n)$.  You don't need to show $P(n)$ holds for the smallest value of $n$, since it is vacuously true that $P(m)$ holds for all smaller values, and therefore the thing proved in the inductive step entails the smallest instance as a special case.

This works not only for natural numbers, but for infinite ordinals.

Comment: “Integers” here should be “natural numbers”, right?  (Not editing it myself in case you’re making a clever point that I’m missing.)

Comment: @Peter: Yes.

.........

Comment: (The software wouldn't let me post that simple response without those trailing dots because it was too short!  Just as with the title of the thread.)

Comment: Oh            ?

Comment: Concerning strong induction without a base case, see Bjorn Poonen's question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11964/strong-induction-without-a-base-case. 

Comment: You can get around that by adding internal spaces

Comment: see           ?

Comment: This can be seen as a special case of [epsilon induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon-induction) with the added hypothesis that $x \in \omega$, since natural numbers are just finite ordinals.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to define the value of the Euler's function $\varphi$ at infinity, the best choice will be $\varphi(\infty)=2$ This is because $\varphi(n)$ is the number of generating elements in the cyclic group of order $n$, and so if $n\to \infty$, the the cyclic group tends to $\mathbb{Z}$ which has just two generating elements.

$0^0=1$ is another example, which is easy to prove for the **natural** zero, but it is not true for the **real** zero!

Comment: If the _base_ is the _real_ or _complex_ zero and the _exponent_ is the _natural_ zero, then $0^0=1$.  For example: $\displaystyle e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$.  If $z=0$, then the first term in this expansion is $0^0/0!=1$.

Comment: Yes you are right, only exponent should be Natural.

Comment: I've just seen this. Surely ${\bf Z}$ is **singly generated**

Comment: @YemonChoi, I think that "the number of generating elements" means "the number of elements that form singleton generating sets", rather than "the minimum cardinality of a generating set".

Comment: I think that's an argument for setting the value *at zero* — as it is the number of generating elements of $\mathbb Z/0\mathbb Z$.

Comment: -1 for “It is not true for real zero.” I’d like to see an argument for this. Real exponentiation is an *extension* of natural exponentiation, i.e. it ought to have the same value wherever the latter is defined.

Comment: Real exponentiation is not an extension of natural exponentiation, they just happen to coincide where both are defined. $\prod_{k \in [0, y) \cap \mathbb Z} x$ is the empty product for $y = 0$ and therefore equal to 1 regardless of the value of $x$, but $\exp(y \ln(x))$ is undefined for $x = 0$ and cannot be defined at $x = y = 0$ while maintaining continuity with respect to both variables.

Comment: @user3840170 Of course it’s not continuous at 0. That doesn’t mean it has to be undefined at 0. The sign function is discontinuous at 0, but there are good reasons to let it be 0 there.

Comment: @user3840170 And yes, real exponentiation “out to be” an extension of natural exponentiation (in particular, it “ought to be” defined wherever the latter is defined). This is the most natural convention, IMO, and there is no downside to it. The continuity point is moot, since $x^y$ will never be continuous anyway.

Comment: The conflaton of $x \uparrow y := \prod_{k\in(y, 0]\cap\mathbb{Z}} \frac 1 x \cdot \prod_{k\in[0, y)\cap\mathbb{Z}} x$ with $\exp(y\ln(x))$ by the notation $x^y$ is a mistake, and the question of how to define $0^0$ is just one piece of evidence against it: some situations demand one convention, [others demand another](https://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2013/03/22/modes-medians-and-means-an-unifying-perspective/). Another is that $(-1) \uparrow k$ is perfectly straightforward, but $\exp(k\ln(-1))$ is meaningless.

Comment: The convention $0^0=1$ in real or complex setting is implicitly assumed when we write a power series $\sum_{k=0}c_kz^k$. Noboby wants to write a generic power series as $c_0+\sum_{k=1}c_kz^k$.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of examples from logic.

Many-sorted first-order logic with 0 sorts is propositional logic. A 0-ary function symbol is a constant symbol, and a 0-ary relation symbol is a proposition. These “degenerate” cases are actually quite interesting and important.

Answer (score 0):

Is the span of the empty set in a vector space equal to $\lbrace 0\rbrace$, or does it have no span? The "correct" answer in my opinion is the latter. See Example 3.10.3 of [https://web.archive.org/web/20201101123724id_/http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20201101123724id_/http://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/ec/ec1.pdf) for a reason:

> **3.10.3 Example.** We give one simple example of the use of equation (3.34). We wish to count the number of spanning subsets of $V_n$. For the purpose of this example, we say that the empty set $\emptyset$ spans no space, while the subset $\{0\}$ spans the zero-dimensional subspace $\{0\}$.* If $W \in B_n(q)$, then let $f(W)$ be the number of subsets of $V_n$ whose span is $W$, and let $g(W)$ be the number whose span is contained in $W$. Hence $g(W) = 2^{q^{\dim W}} − 1$, since $\emptyset$ has no span. Clearly
> $$ g(W) = \sum_{T \le W} f(T) $$
> so by Möbius inversion in $B_n(q)$,
> $$ f(W) = \sum_{T \le W} g(T) \mu(T, W) $$
> Putting $W = V_n$, there follows
> $$ \begin {aligned}
>   f (V_n) &= \sum_{T \in B_n(q)} g(T) \mu(T, V_n) \\
>           &= \sum_{k=0}^n {\boldsymbol n \choose \boldsymbol k} (-1)^{n-k} q^{n - k \choose 2} ( 2^{q^k} - 1 ).
>   \end {aligned} $$
>
> ---
>
> * The standard convention is that the empty set spans $\{0\}$. If we wish to retain this convention, then we need to enlarge $B_n(q)$ by adding $\emptyset$ below $\{0\}$.

On the other hand, a reason (which I find unconvincing) for the span to be $\lbrace 0\rbrace$ is given by PBRMEASAP at
https://www.physicsforums.com/archive/index.php/t-84017.html. This site has a discussion of whether the empty set is a vector space. The correct answer is that it isn't, because one of the axioms is the existence of an additive identity 0.

**Update.** I agree with the comments that the span of the empty set is $\lbrace 0\rbrace$. What I said above was foolish.

Comment: Example 3.10.3 gives a formula for the number of spanning sets in an n-dimensional vector space over a finite field when n>0. The fact that the formula gives 1 rather than 2 when n=0 could be taken as evidence that the empty set does not span the 0-dimensional space, but I would much prefer to say that Example 3.10.3 gives a formula for the number of nonempty spanning sets (for all n). 

Comment: I'm afraid I have to disagree with this answer. All sorts of things would break otherwise. For instance, for any set $S$, we want the $K$-vector space $K^S$ of functions $S\to K$ to have a the standard basis $\{e_s | s\in S\}$, where $e_s$ is the delta-function at $s$. When $S$ is empty, this just says that the empty set (which has zero elements) is a basis for the zero vector space (which has dimension zero). It would be a big nuisance to have say that the empty subset does not have a span. Then you'd have to add exceptions to lots of theorems that would otherwise be true without restriction.

Comment: Any reasonable definition of a span implies that the span of the empty set in a vector space is the zero subspace. No "convention" here:

(1) It is the smallest vector subspace containing $\emptyset$.

(2) It is the set of (finite) linear combinations of elements of $\emptyset$: the only such thing is the empty sum, which is 0.



Comment: Is there a way to upvote the EC1 link without upvoting the whole posting?

Comment: If you don't allow the empty set to span {0}, how on Earth are you going to define dim {0}?  ({0} is not a basis for {0}, since 0 is a linear combination of elements of {0} in two ways.) 

Comment: There is a neat article by de Boor [An empty exercise](http://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/Approx/empty.pdf)
 ([doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145%2F122272.122273)), where he argues for the inclusion of $0\times n$ and $m \times 0$ matrices in Matlab. He discusses definitions of span and determinant etc. I found this from a link on the Wikipedia page for determinant.